# dynamic memory allocation template class

Tags: c++, templates

I am attempting to create a dynamic memory for this class i have created:

```
 #ifndef STACK_H
  #define STACK_H
  #include <stdexcept> 
  #include "Link.h"
  template <class T>
  struct stack{

     Link<T> * head;

    stack();
    void push(T * data);
    T* top();
    T* pop();
    void cleanup();
 };

 #endif
```

src file:

```
#include "stack.h"
  #include <cstddef>
  template <class T>
  stack<T>::stack(){

     head=nullptr;

  }
```

driver:

```
#include "stack.h"
  #include <iostream>
  #include <memory>
  int main(){
     stack<double>  oneStack();
     stack<double>  * oneStack2=new stack<double>;
  }
```

When I compile the code I get the following error:
g++ -Wall  driver.o Link.o stack.o  -o driver.exe
driver.o: In function `main':
driver.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to`stack::stack()'

for some reason using the new keyword is causing this error?

Comment: Please do not post line numbers, and of course have template definitions in the header.

Comment: Is it legal to have `template<class T>` for structs because I usually use typename instead.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson: because in this case, a `struct` is nothing more or less than a `class` and can have a ctor.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson It's legal to have a struct with constructors.

Comment: @DieterLücking Why no line numbers? Is it because this particular problem doesn't show compiler errors which the line numbers would help reference? Or is there a reason for this guideline in general?

Comment: @Pradhan Just copy and paste to compile the code (if  a specific line is troublesome you may put  a comment)

Comment: @DieterLücking Ah of course. Line numbers prevent copy/paste to reproduce :)

Comment: I removed the line numbers per request.  thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are writing template class, you need to define function in the same place where you declare it, so you should probably write it like this

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H
#include <stdexcept> 
#include "Link.h"
template <class T>
struct stack{
    Link<T> * head;

    stack()
    {
        // Constructor code goes here
    }

    void push(T * data)
    {
        // Method code goes here
    }
    T* top()
    {
        // Method code goes here
    }
    T* pop()
    {
        // You get the idea
    }
    void cleanup()
    {
        // ...
    }
};

#endif
```

The reason why compiler needs the template classes and functions to be declared and defined in the same place is that it actually generates a new class for every different set of templates parameters that are used in your code. So, imagine you have `.h` file with declaration of template class and it's methods, and you have a `.cpp` file where these methods are defined. The compiler tries to compile `.cpp` file into an `.obj` file that will later be used to link code into a single executable or library file. But it can't do so, because it doesn't have template parameters **right now in this file**, so it can't actually generate a concrete code for a concrete parameters. Something like this.

If you want a better insight, you can look here: http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl

Comment: He could save the function definitions in a .hpp.

Comment: It just needs to be visible, so e.g. a header file would suffice.

Comment: It does appear i was including the .cpp in driver.cpp before.  That would explain why when I went to using separate compilation my program gave the above error.  Thanks for your clear explanation.

Comment: Also it appears to be supplying the int parameter by default when it creates the .o file.

Comment: No problem. Including `.cpp` is never a good option, especially because noone will ever put include-guards there and you can end up with symbol redifinition. Also, don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem.